# Is it possible to access multiple response headers of the same kind?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, http-headers, response

With the following code:

```
URLRequestDefaults.manageCookies = false;

var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
urlRequest.url = 'http://example.com/some/file/sending/multiple/same/headers';
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
try
{
    urlLoader.addEventListener( HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS, function( event:HTTPStatusEvent ):void {
        trace( 'response headers length: ' + event.responseHeaders.length );
        for each( var responseHeader:URLRequestHeader in event.responseHeaders )
        {
            trace( responseHeader.name + ': ' + responseHeader.value );
        }
    } );
    urlLoader.load( urlRequest );
}
catch( error:SecurityError )
{
    trace( 'A SecurityError has occurred.' );
}
```

... I'm trying to access multiple `Set-Cookie` response headers, but this doesn't seem possible. It seems that AIR overwrites earlier received response headers of the same kind.

Is there any way to circumvent this behaviour, without, for instance, having to use/write a Socket based HTTP client?

**edit:**

Just to clear up possible confusion: I'm talking about multiple `Set-Cookie` response headers received in a single response.

Comment: Did you tried with manageCookies=true; ? In this case cookies whould be handled automatically, hance they might exists for several calls without overwriting.

Comment: @SantgMirian With `manageCookies=true` no `Set-Cookie` header will be readable at all. That's why I need `manageCookies=false`.

Comment: Can you give us a sample response and the trace you are getting from it?

Comment: @kakridge Thanks to your investigative question I have managed to solve the issue. I was convinced that a PHP [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) call (that I use to build the response with) defaulted to *not* replacing earlier similar headers, but it turned out it was the other way around. :-/ Sorry about that. After changing the PHP code, I am now able to receive the multiple `Set-Cookie` headers in AIR (although aggregated as a comma-separated header, but that is fine). So, thank you. If you somehow know how to formulate a relevant answer, I'll award the bounty.

Comment: @fireeyedboy I have added the answer as requested.  Glad to hear things worked out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct to me.  The issue is likely the response you are getting.

Comment: Bounty coming your way in about a day. Thanks again.